# how to deploy magento pwa studio in Cloud

Tags: magento2.3, deployment, pwa

> I want to know how to deploy Magento PWA studio in Cloud
>
> what are technologies required to deploy the Magento PWA studio
>
> aws and digital ocean - both
>
> and what about firebase and aws amplify

Comment: Please Provide information about which Cloud you want to deploy like aws,digitalocean instance or Magento Cloud.

Comment: aws and digital ocean - both

and what about firebase and aws amplify

Comment: you do not want to read stack requirements page??

Comment: then i can deploy to firebase right??

Answer (score 2):

Try magento-upward module from Github link [here](https://github.com/magento-research/magento2-upward-connector).
Refer to the link [here](https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/tutorials/cloud-deploy/) for the official documentation.

Comment: can i upload to already existing server of Magento running server

Comment: @prabhakaran7 yes this will act as any other additional module

Comment: which folder i can upload to server ...

Comment: @prabhakaran7 Please read through https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/tutorials/cloud-deploy/